# Probability of a set $A$ in $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ from Stochastic Calculus for Finance II

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I am currently reading through Steven Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance II; specifically the creation of $\sigma$-algebras and the application of probability measures of their elements. I am asking a question from a provided example which can be found on pages 6-9 (inclusive) of the book.

First, let $\Omega_{\infty}$ be defined as the set of all outcomes from a coin being tossed infinitely many times. That is

$$\Omega_{\infty}:= \{\omega:\omega=w_{1}w_{2}\cdots\},$$

where $w_{i}$ is either heads or tails. Let $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ represent a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega_{\infty}$ such that every $A \in \mathcal{F}_{n}$ represents a permutation of heads and tails of the first $n$ tosses. As an example, one such $A$ could be all $\omega$ where the first $n$ tosses (of an infinite amount) are heads. Another element in $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ could be the set of all $w$ where the first $n$ tosses alternate between heads and tail with $w_{1}$ being heads.

$\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ is then defined to be (as per Shreve's book on page 6):

> We create a $\sigma$-algebra, called $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ by putting in every set that can be described in terms of finitely many coin tosses and then adding all other sets required in order to have a $\sigma$-algebra.

I believe this will eventually generalise the idea behind $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ through the unions and intersections of sets in the $\sigma$-algebra.

An example of a set in $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ is then studied to demonstrate a *tricky/interesting* construction. That is, let $A$ be a set of elements in $\Omega_\infty$ defined as follows:

$$ A:= \left\{\omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H_{n}(\omega)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\right\},$$

where $H_{n}(\omega)$ is the number of heads in the first $n$ tosses of an infinite number of tosses. The definition for $A$ basically says $\omega \in A$ if the average number of heads, as the number of first tosses considered goes to infinity, will be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Next, it is shown that this set $A$ is in $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$. Since only a finite number of tosses are considered to define $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$, the proof is performed by defining the following set $A_{n,m}$ as

$$A_{n,m}:= \left\{\omega: \left\vert \frac{H_{n}(\omega)}{n} - \frac{1}{2} \right\vert \leq \frac{1}{m} \right\}$$

Since $A_{n,m}$ is defined by a finite number of $n$ (first) tosses it is in $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$. By applying the definition of the limit that for all $m > 0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\omega \in A_{n,m}$, it is shown that

$$ A = \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}A_{n,m}.$$

Since $A$ is constructed by the unions and intersections of $A_{n,m} \in \mathcal{F}_{\infty}$, it is concluded that $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\infty}$.

Finally to my question. I want to understand how the probability measure is applied to $A$. The probability measure on sets in $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ is defined as:

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = p^{n_{H}}q^{n-n_{H}},$$

where $n_{H}$ is the number of heads in the first $n$ tosses in $\omega \in A$.

So back to the *complicated* $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\infty}$, Shreve on page 7 says:

> ...the Strong Law of Large Numbers asserts that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ if $p = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$ if $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$

Can someone please explain how the Strong Law of Large Numbers is applied to determine the probability measure of $A$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The strong law of large numbers implies $$P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H_n(\omega)}{n} = p\right) = 1.$$ From here, you can immediately answer your last question by referring to the original definition of your $A$.
- Although $A \in \mathcal{F}_\infty$, it does not belong to $\mathcal{F}_n$ for any $n$, so the formula involving $p$ and $q$ above your last yellow box does not apply.

Comment: Ah interesting! So gathering my thoughts here, the fact that

$$\mathbb{P} \left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{H_{n}(\omega)}{n}=p \right) = 1, $$

implies that every $\omega \in \Omega_{\infty}$ is in $A$, since all $\omega$ will satisfy the definition of $A$. Therefore,

$$\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(\Omega_{\infty})=1,$$

with the latter result being part of the definition of the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$. If the logic is correct here then I am pleased with the conclusion.

Comment: @GustavoLouisG.Montańo No, $P(A)=1$ does not imply $A=\Omega_\infty$. The set of $\omega \in \Omega_\infty$ that are not in $A$ has probability $P(\Omega_\infty \setminus A) = 0$, but can be nonempty.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I mean't that. Let me start again.


 (1). By the law of large numbers, for all $\omega \in \Omega_{\infty}$: if $p = \frac{1}{2}$ then $$\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H_n(\omega)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\right) = 1.$$

 (2). Therefore, for all $\omega \in \Omega_{\infty}$ the requirement for $\omega$ to be in $A$ according to:$$ A:= \left\{\omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H_{n}(\omega)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\right\},$$ is *always* satisfied.

Comment: (3). Therefore all $\omega \in \Omega_{\infty}$ is also in $A$. (Of course we should follow the conventional way of showing equality) Hence $A = \Omega_{\infty}$.

 (4). So $\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(\Omega_{\infty})$. Since by definition $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_{\infty})= 1$, therefore $\mathbb{P}(A)=1.$

Comment: @GustavoLouisG.Montańo Again, no, (1), (2), and (3) are wrong. Perhaps the notation is confusing you; let me rewrite my original statement: The law of large numbers implies $$P\left\{\omega : \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H_n(\omega)}{n} = p\right\} = 1.$$ When $p=1/2$, this is exactly saying $P(A)=1$, that 's all. There exist $\omega \notin A$, for example, the infinite sequence of all heads.

Comment: Oh, so my (1) is wrong to begin with. In the 'usual' sense the Strong Law of Large Numbers would imply (1). However, in this world of $\sigma$-algebras and probability measures the SLLN translates to $$\mathbb{P}\left\{\omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H_{n}(\omega)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\right\}=1.$$

Is this right? Thank you for your patience @angryavian.

Comment: @GustavoLouisG.Montańo I don't know what you mean by "usual sense." If you read [any statement of the SLLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) it states that a sample average converges to a mean **almost surely** (which is the $P(\cdots)=1$ statement above), and does *not* claim that the convergence holds for every $\omega$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70973/discussion-between-gustavo-louis-g-montano-and-angryavian).